# $Ax=y$ with a inequality condition Prove every $x_i$ is positive

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Let $x =(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^t,\ y=(y_1,\cdots,y_n)^t$ be vectors satisfying $Ax=y$ and $$\sum_{j\ne i} \max\{a_{ij},0\}<y_i\le a_{ii}+ \sum_{j\ne i}\min\{a_{ij},0\},\forall i=1,\cdots,n$$
Prove that $\forall i,\ x_i>0$.

Comment: It might help to clarify: (i) What is $M_n(\mathbb{R})$? (do you just mean real-valued $n \times n$ matrices?)  (ii) Does $\sum_{j \neq i} \max[a_{ij},0]$ denote a number formed by summing over $n(n-1)$ terms, or does it mean a function of $i$ formed by summing over the $n-1$ terms  $j \in \{1, .., n\} - \{i\}$?

Comment: (i)yes (ii) it's summing over n-1 terms , we have n inequalities

Comment: Well we have for all $i$ that $y_i>0$ and $a_{ii} \geq \sum_{j:j\neq i} |a_{ij}|$.  It may be useful that the largest magnitude component of $x$ is positive, since, if $k$ is the largest magnitude component and $x_k<0$ then $0 < y_k = -a_{kk}|x_k| + \sum_{j:j\neq k} a_{kj} x_j \leq |x_k|(-a_{kk}+\sum_{j:j\neq k}|a_{kj}|) \leq 0$, a contradiction.